# execve(...) does not execute program despite passing in PATH variable

Tags: c++, shell, exec, execve

I'm executing a simple shell program from the directory:

/home/user/shell.exe

Using the code below, I'm able to run files that are in the same folder as my shell executable, but am unable to run programs such as ls.exe.

The tokens container includes the file name as the first element and any subsequent tokens (such as "-l" in the input "ls.exe -l") in the following elements.

```
if (fork())
{
  int status;
  wait(&status);
}
else
{
std::vector<const char*> exeArgs;
std::vector<const char*> envArgs;

std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(),
[&exeArgs](const string& elem){ exeArgs.push_back(elem.c_str()); }
             );

exeArgs.push_back(nullptr);

string path = "PATH=";
path.append(getenv("PATH"));

envArgs.push_back(path.c_str());
envArgs.push_back(nullptr);

if (execve(exeArgs[0], const_cast<char *const *>(&exeArgs[0]),
                       const_cast<char *const *>(&envArgs[0])))
{
  std::cout << word << ": command not found" << std::endl;
  exit(0);
}
}
```

I've spent countless hours just googling and reading the man pages over and over but can't seem to get a clue why this code doesn't work.

The idea is that my shell program should allow users to set the PATH variable and then execute programs with that PATH variable, which is why I have to make execve() work properly instead of just using execvp().

I have a map of shell variables in a separate part of the file but since I can't even get this to work, I thought it would be pointless to include that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* know that the `exec` family of functions *replaces* the current process with the image of the new program? That's why it's so common to use `fork` before `exec`.

Armed with that knowledge, it's easy to find a solution for you, and how you *can* use `execvp` (which you need to use, `execve` doesn't really use the environment you pass, it just passes it along to the new program): You `fork` and use `setenv` to set the `PATH` of the *new* process, before calling `execvp`.

Comment: I edited the post to include the rest of my function.

I'd just like to clarify, if execve() doesn't use the environment variables that are passed in to set the environment variables of the process after loading the new program, then what is the environment variable array parameter for?

Comment: @ozma As I said, it passes the environment on to the *new* program, the one that `exec` executes. If you don't know, in POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS, where `exec` is standardized) the `main` function can have a *third* arguments, usually named `env` and is declared and works similar to the `argv` array. This is the environment passed by `execve` (and which will be available through `getenv` in the new program).

Comment: Oh, right! All this time I assumed that since I was passing in the environment variables, they would also play a part in the execution of the program. This is also the first time I've heard about the third argument for main. Thanks a ton.